# Can a finite verb modify another verb as if it were a gerund? (De manibus delapsa arma ceciderunt)

Tags: verbs, grammar-identification

How should we interpret the connection between *delapsa* and *ceciderunt* in the following:

> de manibus audacissimorum civium **delapsa** arma ipsa **ceciderunt** (Cic. De Officiis)

Naturally I could not see anything special with this sentence (The weapons slipped down and fell). But does the fact that *delabor* and *cado* are strongly semantically related, might give rise to another slightly different interpretation?

---

Context:

Sebastian Castellio translated a part of Gen 2:3 as **creaverat feceratque** (ברא לעשות); [A note](https://books.google.com/books?id=zhXmgodUiykC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=ubi%20duo%20verba%20eiusdem%20notionis%20ponuntur&source=bl&ots=0cJCVsV8Jw&sig=ACfU3U0FkpXlJCgS1HM9dE7DgFf01Gns8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBmISwvNjtAhUI3BoKHffvB0MQ6AEwBXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=ubi%20duo%20verba%20eiusdem%20notionis%20ponuntur&f=false) (I think by Castellio himself) on this part:

> Ad verbum, *creavit faciendo* (nam "*lamed*" saepe gerundivum fecit, ut 2 Sam.[in source *Reg* pro *Sam* but this obviously mistake]. 19. לאהבה , amando) ubi duo verba eiusdem notionis ponuntur. ut in 1. Corinth.18 [...]. Quale est Ciceronis illud: De manibus audacissimorum civium delapsa arma ceciderunt: hoc est, delapsa sunt, & ceciderunt.

This note seems to acknowledge that *creaverat feceratque* is not the literal (*ad verbum*) translation of this part - which is rather, according to the note's author at least, *creavit faciendo* (i.e. created by making). But I don't quite grasp what this note is saying. It does try, I think, to justify the choice of *creaverat feceratque* for the literal *creavit faciendo*, and giving the quoted above example from Cicero, as an example where two verbs sharing roughly the same meaning can act as one is modifying the other as if it were a gerund?

Interestingly, KJV also chose the phrase *created and made* for this part, so maybe this mechanism applies also to the English language (though judging by the last sentence of [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29415/why-is-this-verb-%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%A9%D7%82%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA-infinitive-gn-23/29461#29461) is not always recognized)

Comment: Castellio doesn't have to be right. Delapsa is probably not a finite verb, but the perfect participle. "The weapons, having slipped, fell." I'll write a fuller answer later.